# Why does an oven plug burn out when all knobs are on full-setting?

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, current, resistors, resistance

I'm having serious trouble understanding this. If a component burns out when too much current is flowing through it, then how does turning on all stove-tops to their full setting burn out the oven's wall-plug?

Shouldn't turning on all the stove-tops increase resistance as you're adding more components to the circuit? Can someone explain (in simple terms) why this happens, also referring to mains supply and wall plugs and series/parallel phenomena. A diagram would help too I guess.

Comment: Your question title seems incorrect. There is nothing in your post that suggests that your oven has burnt out or failed in any way.

Comment: Let me change it.

Comment: More resistances in parallel REDUCE the overall resistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If a fuse burns out when too much current is flowing through it, then how does turning on all knobs to their full setting burn out the wall-plug?

Turning on more rings will draw more current (in the same way that turning on more water taps will draw more water current). If the wall-plug burns out then it is inadequate for the job.

> Shouldn't turning on all knobs increase resistance as you're adding more components to the circuit?

No. Turning on more cooker rings adds more resistors in  parallel and that *decreases* reseistance.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpbxVV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Switching on additional heaters adds resistance in parallel. This reduces the overall resistance allowing more current to flow from the mains supply.*

To understand how the power setting knobs work see my answer to 
[Setting heat on electric stove](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/252352/setting-heat-on-electric-stove/252357#252357).

Comment: You are one hell of a genius. Thank you, Sir Transistor!